# Qt seg fault running on Ubuntu: no termal display QML konsole

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5

I'm compiling and attempting to run [cool-retro-term](https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term) on Ubuntu. It appears to compile successfully, but when I run it, I get a Qt-related segmentation fault:

```
>./cool-retro-term
default KB_LAYOUT_DIR:  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QMLTermWidget/kb-layouts"
QObject::connect: No such slot Konsole::TerminalDisplay_QML_56::close()
loadAllColorSchemes
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Would anyone have any guesses about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Do you have all of the dependencies installed in place? Also, which version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: @mutantkeyboard Yup, I'm on Ubuntu 16.10 and have all of the stated dependencies installed: `sudo apt-get install build-essential qmlscene qt5-qmake qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin libqt5qml-graphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin qtdeclarative5-window-plugin`.

Comment: Ok. Could you try doing `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, and try to recompile the program again? Also I've been following the bugs on the cool-retro-term itself, and seems like the problem has been there for a while. [Here](https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term/issues/18)